# Search results template listing all posts

Tags: php, search

Hi there having a problem with my search results page - basically it is listing all pages rather than narrowing it down to only those involving the search query.

I suspect I need to make use of `get_search_query` Is there something I can put in my args so that the search query is used in query_posts?

```
<?php 
  $args =  array('post_type'=>array('page'), 'posts_per_page' => 6 );

  query_posts($args);

  if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

?>


<a href="<?php the_permalink();?>" title="<?php the_title();?>"><?php the_title();?></a>


<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php else :  // no results?>
    <p>No Pages Found.</p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out with some research

See the updated args

```
      $s = isset( $_GET["s"] ) ? $_GET["s"] : "";

  $args = array(
    's' => $s,
    'post_type'=>array('page'),
    'posts_per_page' => 6 
    );

  query_posts($args);


  if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
```